# Wordpress custom image size and set srcset manually without using wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-rest-api

I am using wordpress as a content writing interface. In my project, what I am doing is let users create blogs which may include text content and images. I have my own server from where I host these blogs. So I make API call to fetch the data about the blog and then render it using my own custom template.

I'll explain the problem using an example.

1. I created a blog, which contains text content and an image named `image-1`. The slug for blog is `my-blog`.
2. I have `json-api` plugin using which I can make an API call to get all the data about a blog.
3. A user try to access the blog, the request reach server. On server I make an API call to wordpress for blog `my-blog`, gets the response and return the rendered content to the browser.
4. For image `image-1` , wordpress give me three versions of different sizes. These are not satisfactory for me.

PROBLEM: I want to upload my own versions of `image-1` named `image-1-small` and `image-1-large`. Also I myself want to set the `srcset` attribute in the `image` tag for `image-1` so that proper version of image be rendered on different view ports.

How may I achieve this.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am trying to do the same.

Comment: @TJSherrill I don't remember exactly what I did but I had to make some changes in the theme.